# Pieces of image stick around after altering display to "display: none"

Tags: javascript, html

I've been using the following function to hide my div's when I no longer wanted them to be visible

```
function hide(div) {
  document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
}
```

However the problem has arrived with the div inparticular.

```
<div id="loading">
    <img src="./img/loading.gif"/>
</div>
```

When I call the function `hide('loading')` only parts are the image are hidden, and slices of it are burnt onto the page. Considering this is supposed to be a little loading icon, having is stamped into the page isn't really what I'm going for, how can I prevent this?

I'm using the loading icon while processing network data, then hiding it upon receiving and processing data from the server(nodejs).

css as requested:

```
#loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -64px;
  margin-left: -64px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Can you not add display none to the image? Is it okay if you share a fiddle so we can see what it's doing, it might be a css thing is the loader positioned?

Comment: I added the css to the OP, it's positioned using fixed

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you provide a minimal reproduction?

Comment: @recursive - Everything needed to reproduce is in the post :/

Comment: @Christian.tucker:  No, there is not enough to reproduce here.  http://jsfiddle.net/vq4gwLpe/

Answer (score 0):

can u try this..??

**Html**

```
<div id="one">
    <img src="https://elora.aerb.gov.in/ELORA/images/loadingnew.gif">
</div>
<div id="two">
    <img src="http://www.schultzlawoffice.com/img/loading/loading.gif">
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").on("click", function () {
        var thisId = $(this)
        hide(thisId);
    });

});

function hide(thisId) {
    $(thisId).hide();
}
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uq0e9vg2/)

Comment: Not using jQuery as it causes complications when compiling to mobile, either way this is just making sure the the DOM is ready before calling the hide(). The DOM is ready before anything is displayed on my application. I have it set like so.